# Display legend for Tableau Chart

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau I created an Area chart. I have managed to display legend for the measure values but cannot legend one for the grey line (additional measure in Rows) as I have built a dual axis chart.

Could some one guide me how this could be done. Apologies if the question is unclear. Can provide more details if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a worksheet then

1. Select Analysis > Legends > Color Legend.
2. Select Worksheet > Show Cards > Reset Cards.
3. Right-click in the space below the Marks card and select Legends >
   Color Legend.

If you have dual axis, ensure transparency is **100%** on the first pill else the colors in legend will not show up.

EDIT:

In case you have already done that, try using the **All** marks card (the top one), put Measure Names on the color shelf